# Does the German version of Mass Effect 3 contain an English language pack?

Tags: mass-effect-3

As the German localizations of computer games are usually not up to the standards of the English original, I'd like to play Mass Effect 3 in English. Getting the retail English versions is often annoying in Germany, and the digital version at Origin is significantly more expensive than the German version at Amazon.

So, does the German retail version of Mass Effect 3 contain the English voice overs and all the rest of the game in English? Or is it a German-only version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I now bought the game I can confirm that the german retail version contains english voicovers and everything. Just select "English" as language when the installer starts.

Answer (score 4):

The product description on the [German Amazon page](http://www.amazon.de/EA-Mass-Effect-3/dp/B004FPYHBE/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1330538427&sr=8-1) states, that you can play in either English or German, explicitely naming text and audio.

Comment: Hmm, I only read as far as the general information about the game, where Amazon lists "Deutsch, Deutsch" as language, which contradicts the product description.